# Is $28$ the only perfect number that is form of $n^n+1$?

Tags: number-theory, perfect-numbers

Is $28$ the only perfect number that is form of $n^n+1$?

I noticed that in the sequence of $n^n+1$, $28$ is the only perfect number that is in the list.

Using Pari GP, I checked the values of $n\leq10^{4}$, but it seems that $28$ is the only perfect number showed in the list.

I think that $n+1$ must be divisible by $4$ in order for $n^n+1$ be a perfect number.

Note that $n\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$.

Comment: Do you mean you checked $n\leq 10^4?$ Because there are a lot of $n\geq 10^4$ values to check...

Comment: The perfect numbers we know are all of the form $2^{p-1}(2^p-1),$ where $2^p-1$ is prime. Those are all of the even perfect numbers. We don't know if there are any odd perfect numbers, still.

Comment: If $$n^n\equiv -1\pmod {2^{p-1}},$$ I think you can show that $n\equiv -1\pmod {2^{p-1}}$ and this $n^n>2^{n(p-2)}>2^{2p-1}$ for $n>3$ and $p>4.$ That handles the even perfect numbers.

Comment: For the even case , I suggest to check for the known $51$ even perfect numbers $P$ , whether $P-1$ is a perfect power. This should be no problem in PARI/GP. The odd case is more challenging , but the existence of an odd perfect numer is anyway extremely unlikely.

Comment: For the known even perfect numbers $P$ , neither $P-1$ nor $P+1$ is a perfect power except $28-1=3^3$.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers), any odd perfect number is equal to 1 mod 12, or 117 mod 468, or 81 mod 324. I checked every n up to 100,000, and got that this is equivalent to n being divisible by 6. I think this should extend to all n by an argument involving Euler's theorem?

Comment: @pastebee Considering that we know that there is no odd perfect number below $10^{1500}$ (among many other things) and that we basically had to factor numbers of the form $n^n+1$ with more than $1500$ digits , I do not think that this helps much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can give you an answer for even perfect numbers.

**Lemma:** If $a,b\in\mathbb N$ such that $a^b\equiv -1\pmod{2^k}$ for $k\geq 1,$ then $a\equiv -1\pmod{2^k}.$

**Proof:** By induction on $k.$

I leave it to you to show $k=1.$

If true for $k,$ and $a^b\equiv -1\pmod{2^{k+1}}$ then $a^b\equiv -1\pmod{2^k}$ and hence, by the induction hypothesis, $a\equiv -1\pmod{2^k}.$

This means that $a\equiv -1$ or $a\equiv 2^k-1$ $\pmod{2^{k+1}}.$

If $a\equiv 2^k-1\pmod{2^{k+1}},$ then: $$a^2\equiv 2^{2k}-2\cdot 2^k+1\equiv 1\pmod{2^{k+1}}.$$ So it is not possible for $a^b\equiv -1\pmod{2^{k+1}},$ it only takes values $1$ and $a.$

---

The even perfect numbers are of the form $m_k=2^{k}(2^{k+1}-1)$ where $2^{k+1}-1$ is prime.

We will show that, for $k\geq 3,$ $m_k$ can't be written as $n^n+1,$ whether $m_k$ is perfect or not.

If $n^n+1=m_k,$ then, in particular, $n^n\equiv -1\pmod{2^k},$ and thus $n\equiv -1\pmod{2^k}$ by the lemma.

But then $n\geq 2^{k}-1>2^{k-1}$ so $n^n>2^{(2^k-1)(k-1)}.$

And $m_k<2^{2k-1}.$

So all that is left is to show $(2^k-1)(k-1)> 2k-1$ for $k\geq 3.$ (When $k=2,$ the two values are equal, yielding your one example.)

Now, $2^k\geq k+1,$ so it is enough to show $k(k-1)> 2k-1$ or $k(k-3)\geq -1$ for $k\geq 3.$ But that is trivially true.

---

So we've proven it for all even perfect numbers.

The question is whether we know enough about possible odd perfect numbers to eliminate those cases, too. There are a lot of theorems of the form: "If $m$ is an odd perfect number, then ..." But I don't know them well enough to say if we can deduce this.

Certainly, it would mean $n$ must be even and hence $m\equiv 1\pmod{2^n}.$

It also means $m=1+c^2$ where $c=n^{n/2}$ This means the prime factors of $m$ must all be $\equiv 1\pmod 4.$